# Finding what is referencing some assembly

Tags: c#, .net, mono

When I get a CS1701 error, such as the following, how can I find what is referencing this assembly? I do not have access to Visual Studio - only the CLI apps available through Mono (meaning I can run any CLR app).

> Web.csproj (default targets) ->
>   /usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.2.2.30/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets
>   (CoreCompile target) ->
>
> CSC: error CS1701: Warning as Error: Assuming assembly reference 
>   Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' matches assemblyNewtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
>   You may need to supply runtime policy

Comment: `ikdasm` or `monodis` to disassemble the CIL, both will show ref'd assemblies...

Comment: That seems like an answer to me? I'll check it out in the morning (it's 2am here)